# Find the most common word in a text

Tags: java, algorithm, hashmap, bufferedreader

I am given a text on several lines. I have to find the most common word and, if more words appear as many times as the one I am looking for, I have to display the smallest lexicographic.

I think I should use a `HashMap`, but I don't know where to start.

I tried this:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String line, word = "";
        int count = 0, maxCount = 0;
        ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String string[] = line.toLowerCase().split("([,.\\s]+) ");
            for(String s : string){
                words.add(s);
            }
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++){
            count = 1;
            for(int j = i+1; j < words.size(); j++){
                if(words.get(i).equals(words.get(j))){
                    count++;
                }
            }
            if(count > maxCount){
                maxCount = count;
                word = words.get(i);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(word);
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't have to use a HashMap. ArrayList would work too. I think you're on a good way to solving this already. I'd suggest breaking up the problem into smaller parts and cases and then go with that. For example, start with reading in the words from an example file. Does it work? Is it the same amount of words as expected? Then go to the next stage, find the most common word. Is it able to do that? Can you handle cases where there's multiple "most common" ones. And so on. I'd strongly recommending println each part.

Comment: May consider this change to use a Hashmap ... Instead of ArrayList "words" take a hashmap Map<String, Integer> words= new HashMap<String, Integer>();    Then check if map contains your actual word as key : if not put it inside the map with value 1 else increase the value

Answer (score 3):

You're correct when thinking about the `HashMap` approach for this problem.

HashMap can contain a unique word which is a key and its frequency which is a value.

```
Map<String, Integer> wordCounts = new HashMap<>();
```

You also don't need to use a list to contain your words. Put them directly to a map.

Here is an example:

```
    String[]  words = line.toLowerCase().split("([,.\\s]+) ");
    for(String s: words){
        //get a current frequency or set to be 0 if it doesn't exist.
        Integer freq = wordCounts.getOrDefault(s, 0);
        wordCounts.put(s, freq+1);
    }
```

It hasn't been finished yet. Looping over the entries of `wordCounts` to find the most common word.

```
int max = 0;
String word = null;
for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry: wordCounts.entrySet()) {
     if(entry.getValue() > max) {
         max = entry.getValue();
         word = entry.getKey();
     }
}
```

Comment: Good answer, though I would use the name `wordCounts`, rather than `result` which conveys no meaning about the contents of the map.

Comment: @VGR, cannot agree more :-). Will update it to make it better.

Comment: @TranHo Complete your answer by taking the max count and smallest lexicographically among them.

Comment: @vivek_23, haha, almost forgot. I will update it :D. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is the process I would follow...

1. Loop through all of the words
2. Create a `HashMap<String, Integer>`. The String is the key, this will be where you store your words. The Integer is the value, this will store the frequency of words.
3. While looping through the words, put them to the HashMap, if that key (the word) already exists, replace the value with the (current value + 1). This will keep track of how many times the word appears.
4. When you are done looping through the words, iterate through the HashMap, remembering the currently known maximum and the key that's paired to it. Once it is done you will have the maximum.

Comment: I upvoted due to the same idea but my answer posted faster than yours 1 second. :D

Comment: @TranHo looks like you beat me to it, will upvote yours since it has code example 